# Google maps api on User defined image

Tags: image, google-maps, focus

Would anyone please tell me if is it possible to use the functionalities of Google maps api (like focusing and zooming in) not on a map but on a user defined image( in .png or .jpeg formats). If yes, how to do it? I have been googling it for a couple of days but i cant get an exact answer for my question. Sorry for being silly but I am new to programming. Hope someone will help me.

Comment: yes, we can do that....

Comment: did you define your images in your xml?
can your share your xml with us??

Comment: no.. wat i mean is consider a normal jpeg image(say someone's picture), can we apply google maps functionality on that image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_zoom_in" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_out"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_location"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_zoom_out" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_zoom_in"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_location" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Activity:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_location:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location
                .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        break;
    case R.id.btn_zoom_in:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        break;
    case R.id.btn_zoom_out:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

i hope it would solve your problem.... :)

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly fine. But what i asked is about custom image map types in google maps api v3. Now i found it. Anyway thanks alot :)